# How can I change the data type to an auto increment when starting with letters

Tags: sql-server

update I have a database with 5 tables in. Without using pictures its hard to describe but I will do my best. I used a flat file insert data

The first table was books with the following columns in

```
Bookid ISBN Category title Author Publisher Paperback_hardback Number of pages.
```

BookID features in other tables

The second table was customer

```
CustomerID, Customer_firstname, Surname, Address, town, contact number.
```

Third table
Then I have order table which makes use of the customer ID (from customer table) as a foreign key and recognises the bookID from the books table

```
OrderID Customer
Order ID, CustomerID, BookID, Salesdate, Quantitysold, costofbook
```

I want to change it so the customer ID goes from CS01 to CS02 the to CS03 etc every time a new customer is added.  The customerID is used as a foreign key in order table so needs to be linked.

In basic terms add 1 to the previous customerID when a new customer is added. It is currently Char(10).

Really sorry this is messy but I cannot copy images or use tables in this message.

I have designed a table called customer (see link )  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaXAQ.png)each customer has an ID that I have set as a CS then a number. I want the number to auto increase when a new customer is added. I am trying to alter the table by using the following code

[MY CODE AS SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWYqz.png)

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
ALTER COLUMN CustomerID

DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR (10) = 'CS'
DECLARE @STRING2 INT =1

SELECT CONCAT (@STRING, @STRING2),
@STRING + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @STRING 2)
```

Is there another way I can change the CustomerID column so it uses auto increment with CS infront of the numbers?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on posting

Comment: Sorry had a typo. You could create a regular identity column and then create a computed column like: `alter table customers add ID INT IDENTITY; alter table customers add CustomerID as CONCAT('CS', ID)`

Comment: @siggemannen  thanks for your help, I still get an  error message but will keep trying. I am new to sql

Comment: It's always good to post exact message you're getting :)

Comment: @siggemannen  I pressed enter too early and it sent. msg 2705 Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ID' in table 'customers' is specified more than once.

Comment: wait, i think there's something wrong. if you have an order table, then you should have a customer table. you have duplicate customers already in the table, so what you're asking doesn't make sense. I take it all back. You should post your whole design and explain what you're trying to do

Comment: Please add the complete design of your table, and specify exact what result you expect with some sample data

Comment: So what is your existing `ID` column in the table? is that a `IDENTITY` already?

Comment: What is the point of sticking the string CS to the front of every row in the table? That is just storing a whole bunch of data that is not only a duplicate, it is meaningless. I would think about why you want the prefix on your customer number. Do you really need it? What purpose or benefit does that provide?

Comment: From looking at your order table you either have some normalization issues or a strange restriction. It seems that from your design a given can have only one book but it can be for any quantity? That seems odd as most order systems allow to purchase more than one item in a single purchase.

Comment: @SeanLange its so it can be identified as customer as there are other ids that are just numbers, I want the customer ID to stand out in the table when there is an Order ID, and Book ID

Comment: Then you should use another column like IsCustomer. What you are doing violates 1NF by stuffing additional pieces of information into a value.

Comment: Im not stuffing additional information in. The customer ID I always wanted as CS01 and so on, but I had to use a flat file to install data.  I do not want extra columns for ID al I wanted to do was change CHAR10 so that if I add a new customer it generates a new customer ID. It appears I can't change CHAR(10) with a statement. All I wanted from the start was one column called customerID that went CS01, CS02, CS03, CS04. From using a flat file this is not possible. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: so why don't you show us that flat file, and why don't you explain this from the start. You had us finding a solution to a different problem that you are facing. How are we supposed to know that. It would be best for you to make a new question here and ask the correct question this time, and give us enough information, like a part of the content of the flat file, the schema of your table and what you expect as result

Comment: @GuidoG I wil do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is like siggemannen suggested, add a calculated field.
You can add a simple one like this

```
alter table customer
add customerid as 'CS' + convert(varchar(10), id)
```

result is something like this

| id | name | customerid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jef | CS1 |
| 2 | john | CS2 |
| 3 | samanta | CS3 |

or with leftpad like this

```
alter table customer
add customerid_2 as 'CS' + right('000000' + convert(varchar(10), id), 6)
```

The result looks like this

| id | name | customerid | customerid_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jef | CS1 | CS000001 |
| 2 | john | CS2 | CS000002 |
| 3 | samanta | CS3 | CS000003 |

Check out [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OvTS0lgi) to see this in action

Answer (score 0):

You could define a [sequence number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver16) and then use it to define a default value formula for the id as you want.

This is an example of how it could work.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.EmployeePrimaryKey
AS INT
START WITH 1
MINVALUE 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmployeeKey NVARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT EmployeePK PRIMARY KEY
        DEFAULT FORMAT(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.EmployeePrimaryKey, 'CS000000')
  , EmployeeName VARCHAR(200)
  , Active TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeName, Active)  VALUES 
('Ted', 1),
('Bob', 0);

SELECT * FROM Employee;
```

This is the result:

| EmployeeKey | EmployeeName | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CS000001 | Ted | 1 |
| CS000002 | Bob | 0 |

If you are converting an existing table you could set the start number for the sequence as the next valid number.

Comment: thanks for your help I'll give it a try.  I'm having problems copying and pasting from SQL server. I'm not meant to post photos so its hard trying to explain my whole system without recreating it in a new table in the post.